# Do we really need to validate "file" extensions for externals in the code snippet editor?

Tags: discussion, stack-snippets

As we all know, "file"-suffixes are effectively meaningless w.r.t. HTTP URLs. The type of the resource is determined by the `Content-Type` header, not its path-suffix.

So, I tried to add the following JavaScript package using the "Add an external library" option:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redux

Which yields the following alert message:

[image: Code snippet alert message]

This can easily be circumvented by appending a hash to the end of the URL:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redux#.js

Then I go back into the resultant HTML and remove the hash from the inserted `<script>` tag. It's a pretty annoying workflow. Is it truly necessary?

### Addendum

It appears that the type of markup that is inserted into the html document varies according to this `.css`/`.js` suffix, so it's more than just a validation. Sniffing the content-type is probably out. Couldn't this be represented with a dropdown/radio-buttons instead of being deduced from a compulsory file suffix?

Comment: Is it really easier to use the interface then it is to type out a script tag or a link tag? I can't say I ever remember using that part of the interface.

Comment: @TinyGiant For me, yes. I use it, despite the shortcomings. I rarely work at the HTML rockface, so this saves me a context-switch.

Comment: at what part of the site are you using this?

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout When asking or answering a question, pressing the `JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet` or `Ctrl+M` will get you there.

Comment: Have you considered using `unpkg` instead of `jsdelivr`? When you type in `https://unpkg.com/redux` in the omnibar, it automatically redirects to the umd entry point `https://unpkg.com/redux@4.0.1/dist/redux.js` which you _can_ paste into the interface. Personally I think this is a bit of a non-issue.